# Combining static and dynamic parts in a response header mapping expression

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'd like to build a response header by combining a static part with info from the body, something like:

'/resources/' + integration.response.body.id

That gives me "Invalid mapping expression specified".

Is it not possible, or is my syntax just wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, such complex expressions are not possible in header mapping expressions currently. Header values may be a single mapping expression or a static string value.

This is a request we have heard from other customers and will definitely consider it as we add additional functionally to the service.

Comment: "Content-Disposition" : "'attachment; filename=' + integration.response.header.filename"

Still can't do it :(